# Find specific text until it is found it stops

Tags: php

I was wondering how to do it, this code will as you know get specific line, now I need it to read until a specific text like 55 and stops reading from there. As you can see the log contains some whitespace so what function can I use to read until the code 55?

`$row['MtID']` = A unique ID to specify the line where the result is.

So for example the log of the result will be

MM3,67624563 (Unique ID (MtID),233262345599,http://mywebsite.com:8080/web/mm3_pixel.php?sspdata=ams1CIv44qa26LGkchACGKqShLrCtZieSyINNDEuMTkwLjg4LjIwOCgB&vurlid=993211,http://mywebsite.net/sspx?id=69171&sspdata=ams1CIv44qa26LGkchACGKqShLrCtZieSyINNDEuMTkwLjg4LjIwOCgB >> OK
,55

```
$logfile = file("https://myweb.com/Pixel-Full.php?file=".$country."/".$today."-pixel-response.log");

foreach($logfile as $line_num = > $line) {
    if (strpos($line, $row['MtID']) !== false) {
        $getresult = strstr(htmlspecialchars($line), 'http://');
        echo "<td>".$getresult."</td>";
    }
}
```

This system goes like this, a user request something and nothing found, so on our log, it will post the error link requested by user and the error code for us to know what problem it was. So once the system reads the line and continue to read other line as well until it found the code, it stops

Comment: Your anchor doesnt work. It redirects me to another page

Comment: that link is just an example how the system reports an error.

Comment: good idea not to use "As you know" when it's code we've never seen. That said, who says "55" is not somewhere else in the data, too? Your example link looks like it's missing some code delimiting, can you enclose it in back-ticks, or space it so that it's code, so that we know exactly where you intended newlines to be?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Updated the example links, each "," is a separator for each info, errorcode=33 <-- Error code, success=false <---- Result from our partner, 55 <--- Our technical team error code for reference purpose.

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749415/search-for-a-string-or-part-of-string-in-php

Comment: @Furry I could not understand what's the problem in your code. Do you need it to return the first 55 lines of your log file? or Do you want it to search for something among the first 55 lines and then returns the line number in-which that thing is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $startline = count($logfile)+1;
 foreach($logfile as $line_num => $line) {
     if (strpos($line, $row['MtID']) !== false) {
         $startline = $line_num;
         $getresult = trim(strstr(htmlspecialchars($line), 'http://'));
         if (strpos($getresult, ",55")  !== false) {
            $getresult = substr($getresult,0,strpos($getresult, ",55")+3);
            break;
         }
     }
     if ($line_num > $startline) {
         $getresult .= trim(htmlspecialchars($line));
         if (strpos($getresult, ",55")  !== false) {
            $getresult = substr($getresult,0,strpos($getresult, ",55")+3);
            break;
         }
     }
 }
 echo "<td>".$getresult."</td>";
```

Comment: This is not the answer I want, I need it to loop until it gets the "55" then stops looping and echo the result.

Comment: That looks like what this does. When it matches `$row['MtID']` it echoes the result and then stops the loop with `break`.

Comment: @FabienTheSolution Whether with or without break, the code works fine.

Comment: I think I finally "catched" what you want. Take a look at my new answer.

Comment: @FabienTheSolution Nope, this is not the solution I want, it echo every line in the log. I just want that line + few lines below me and reads the few lines until it found the number "55" then it stops.

Comment: @FabienTheSolution You are close, but it doesn't do what I required. The variable $line_num isn't posting the line I requested, so it won't satisfy the "if" condition.

Comment: Is it a line number that is in `$row['MtID']` or something else? Cause you said that it is "A unique ID to specify the line where the result is"...

Comment: @FabienTheSolution I have updated a real example of my log, see if you understands that.

Comment: @Furry: in general, I'd say it is best to use answers here as clues to your solution. You've been very lucky that you've been able to specify "what you want" in this case, but normally you have to pay a contractor for that level of service! Well done Fabien, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` flag in the [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) call to skip empty lines and then use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to get the part of the array you need.

```
$file = array_slice(file("https://myweb.com/Pixel-Full.php?file={$country}/{$today}-pixel-response.log", FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES), 0, $row['MtID']);

foreach($file as $line) {
    $result = strstr(htmlspecialchars($line), 'http://');
    echo "<td>{$result}</td>";
}
```

Comment: Tried, it doesn't work, and it shows every log result becoming infinite result.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like stopping the execution when a positive match is the biggest trick here. This can be done with a break. (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

```
//get the file as a string
$logfile = file_get_contents("https://myweb.com/Pixel-Full.php?file=".$country."/".$today."-pixel-response.log", false);
//make up some rows and catch the false
if ($logfile !== false) {
    $logrows = explode("\n", $logfile);

    //loop
    foreach($logrows as $line) {
        if (strpos($line, $row['MtID']) !== false) {
            $getresult = strstr(htmlspecialchars($line), 'http://');
            echo "<td>".$getresult."</td>";
            break;
        }
    }
}
else echo "Log resource unavailable";
//some memory clearing
unset($logfile);
unset($logrows);
```

I would suggest for matching sanity that you make sure that the logging format makes the `MtID` variable something that wouldn't be found in the log text unless its a positive match. Using a UUID or a specific ID format would work.

Answer (score 0):

As you regarded, sometimes, the log line may be divided into three lines while in some other times it is only one line:

```
// Three lines
http://www.yourwebsite.com/error/33/happycodingneverending&errorcode=33,
succcess=false;
,55

// one line

http://www.yourwebsite.com/error/33/happycodingneverending&errorcode=33,succcess=false;,55
```

In this case you just have to made a little modification to your code, which, works perfect with only one line example to works with that three lines as follows:

```
foreach($logfile as $line_num = > $line) {
    if (strpos($line, $row['MtID']) !== false) {
        $getresult = strstr(htmlspecialchars($line), 'http://');
        if(!$getresult){
             $theExactLine = $line_num - 2;
             $getresult = $logfile[$theExactLine];        
        }
        echo "<td>".$getresult."</td>";
        break; // to stop looping.
    }
 }
```

Comment: The code seems to have problem. Unexpected end error came out.

Comment: Sorry, it was a missed closing } of foreach. checkout the edit. @Furry