# PHP array keys function contains said value

Tags: php

I'm searching an array for specific values and I was wondering if I can search to see the value contains what I'm searching for, not necessarily an exact match

so..

```
$a = array("red", "reddish", "re", "red diamond");
```

this will only give me 1 key

```
$red = array_keys($a, "red");
```

what if I want all keys that contain the word red.  so I want "red", "reddish" and "red diamond"

or rather I want `0, 1, 3`

Comment: foreach loop then either a preg_match or substr to compare the first 3 letters

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search for a string or part of string in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749415/search-for-a-string-or-part-of-string-in-php)

Comment: @Jef - that is a pretty far stretch. While i see the similarities in the solution, the question is significantly different.

Comment: @SanuelJackson - fair enough.  To me, this is still operationally a "how do I search arrays using substrings" question.  Your answer has better detail than the linked one, in any event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this >  **[Live Demonstration](https://eval.in/136643)**

### Search Specifically for `Red`

```
// Create a function to filter anything 'red'
function red($var) {
  if(strpos($var, 'red') === false) {
      // If array item does not contain red, filter it out by returning false
      return false;
  } else {
      // If array item contains 'red', then keep the item
      return $var;
  }

}


// Set the array (as per your question)
$array = array("red", "reddish", "re", "red diamond");

// This line executes the function red() passing the array to it.    
$newarray = array_filter($array, 'red');

// Dump the results
var_export(  array_keys($newarray) );
```

Use of `array_filter()` or `array_map()` give the developer more control over fast loops through the array for filtering and executing other code.  The function above is designed to do what you request, however it can be as complex as you want.

If you wish to set the value 'red' inside it to be more dynamic, you could do something like the following :

### Generic Search Method

```
// Set the array (as per your question)
$array = array("red", "reddish", "re", "red diamond");

// Set the text you want to filter for    
$color_filter = 'red';

// This line executes the function red() passing the array to it.    
$newarray = array_filter($array, 'dofilter');

// Dump the results
var_export(  array_keys($newarray) );


// Create a function to filter anything 'red'
function dofilter($var) {
  global $color_filter;
  if(strpos($var, $color_filter) === false) {
      // If array item does not contain $color_filter (value), filter it out by returning false
      return false;
  } else {
      // If array item contains $color_filter (value), then keep the item
      return $var;
  }

}
```

Comment: I think it should be `$newarray = array_filter($array, "red");`.

Comment: @SharanyaDutta - yes, i was just correcting that as you wrote that :)

Comment: what do you want it to return.  as it sits, it returns 0,1,3 ... do you want it to return 'red', 'reddish','red diamond' ? .. if so, just change  `var_export(  array_keys($newarray) );` to `var_export(  $newarray );`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_grep`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php):

```
$a = array("red", "reddish", "re", "red diamond");
$red = array_keys(preg_grep("/red/", $a));
print_r($red);
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/136640)

The above code gives you the keys for all values in `$a` that **contain** the string `"red"`. If you need the keys for all values in `$a` that **begin with** the string `"red"`, simply change the regular expression from `"/red/"` to `"/^red/"`.

Comment: I can't even get this past the compiler.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? The function [`preg_grep`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) is available since PHP 4.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array("red", "reddish", "re", "red diamond");

function find_matches( $search, $array )
{
    $keys = array();
    foreach( $array as  $key => $val )
    {
        if( strpos( $val, $search ) !== false )
            $keys[] = $key;
    }
    return $keys;
}
```