# in_array($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], ["/index.php", "/tob.php"]) keeps on returning false

Tags: php

I am trying to check if index.php or tob.php is in the URL of the current page. 
So, I tried to open:

```
/sbfc/public/HR/0-bg.php
```

It gives me **false**, which is expected. However, when I tried to open:

```
/sbfc/public/tob.php
```

Its return value is still **false**.

Any suggestion to rectify this issue? I do have queries in it, i supposed that that isn't the source of issue since i am using "PHP_SELF" instead of "QUERY_STRING".

Thanks in advance!

Edit: **/sbfc/public/HR/0-bg.php** and **/sbfc/public/tob.php** are the result of "PHP_SELF"

Comment: What does `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` return in tob.php ?

Comment: Mean you need to check that current page is one of the from index.php OR tob.php right?

Comment: Yeah, @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd. So, i want it to execute different codes when the user is opening other page instead of index.php or tob.php.

Comment: Use strpos() instead of in_array() http://stackoverflow.com/a/4366748/2878894 Does that help?

Comment: You can try `$homepage = "/index.php";
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($homepage==$currentpage)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) will only search for an exact match of a string. You may be looking for [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) as that will find the first occurrence of a substring in a string. You can use a loop through the array and using strpos() on each iteration to find tob.php

Comment: The data type of $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] per se is not a string, i should convert it to string first in order to use strpos(). I decided to write the absolute path instead of merely /tob.php, and it works! That is strange, i once used in_array() the exact way and it worked. Anw, thanks a heap for the explanation!

Comment: For in_array() the datatypes shouldn't necessary make a different, you can force it to match the datatype that you are using by enabling strict mode (by adding true as a final parameter when using the function). There is more documentation on the PHP website regarding this functionality.

Alternatively, [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) might be more helpful to you as I found in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749415/search-for-a-string-or-part-of-string-in-php).